# In angular 5, what is absolutely necessary in order to route using routerLink to another component view?

Tags: angular, typescript

my router link within company-details.component.html is

```
<a class="btn btn-white btn-xs" [routerLink]="['/companyDetails', nextCompanyID]">
```

within my app.module.ts file the following path is present

```
      { path: 'companyDetails/:companyID', component: CompanyDetailsComponent },
```

company-details.component.ts has

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";

nextCompanyID: number;
```

and

```
  constructor(
private router: Router,
```

...

```
this.nextCompanyID = 2;
```

as necessary.

Im at http://localhost:55588/companyDetails/1 , and when I click the button to navigate, the top bar shows http://localhost:55588/companyDetails/2, but nothing is invoked, such as OnInit. And the view data or lifecycle events dont appear to be re-invoked as expected.

What are the necessary and sufficient steps needed in order for the above routing to work as expected?

the resulting element is

```
<a class="btn btn-white btn-xs" ng-reflect-router-link="/companyDetails,2" href="/companyDetails/2"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
```

which appears okay to me.

something wrong with routerLink?

Ive read
https://v5.angular.io/api/router/RouterLink
and the only clearly defined requirement I can identify is

> If you use dynamic values to generate the link, you can pass an array of path segments, followed by the params for each segment.

I appear to be satisfying this requirement. What else is Required?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post how you grab the params in your `company-details-component`

Comment: @Suryan Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I mean you should do something like in your component i.e. `this.activatedroute.params.subscribe(params => fetch data related to the params here)`

Comment: nextCompanyID: number; and this.nextCompanyID = 2;. Updated above.

Comment: what does activatedRoute have to do with the my above scenario?

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz, so that I can able to understand you more precise, what exactly is your requirement or your issue

Comment: @Suryan Simple Requirement: While currently at http://localhost:55588/companyDetails/1, I need to be able to navigate to http://localhost:55588/companyDetails/2 using a button. Thats it.

Comment: Basically you have a next button, is this what you want in your details component

Answer (score 1):

Angular creates a new component only when you are navigating from different component, but in your case you are trying to navigate to same component. So angular does not create a new component and in turn ngOnInit will not be triggered. If you want companyId

`this.activatedroute.params.subscribe(params => {Get companyId over here})`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` . This is where the content of the navigated route will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

My end solution

```
  ngOnInit() {
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
  s => {
    //  logic here that we want invoked when param is changed
    this.currentCompanyID = +this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params["companyID"];
    this.clearAllForms();
    this.refreshComponentData();
  });
this.refreshComponentData();
```

}

As mentioned above, navigation between the same component doesnt result in ngOnInit() being invoked. The above solution works well.